# How can I install Syspeek in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

SysPeek is a system monitor indicator that displays CPU usage, memory usage, swap usage, disk usage and network traffic.

Is there a version of Syspeek for Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly suggest against using `dpkg -i` to directly install packages since this has the potential to leave your system with unresolved dependencies.

Instead, I rebuilt the Oneiric package for Raring and copied it to my PPA:

> [ppa:george-edison55/george-edison [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/george-edison) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

Unfortunately the Launchpad builders are extremely busy right now and it looks like the package won't be built for another four hours or so. Once it completes, however, you will be able to simply run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:george-edison55/george-edison
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install syspeek
```

Answer (score 1):

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
wget -O syspeek_0.2_all.deb https://launchpadlibrarian.net/83623660/syspeek_0.2~oneiric1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i syspeek_0.2_all.deb
```

When done search for syspeek in dash, and you will get:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Source:[Upubuntu](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/05/list-of-22-application-indicators-for.html)</sup>

Comment: Please don't provide shortened URLs to tell people to wget and install. Please use the full URL, or if it's in a PPA on Launchpad, specify how to add a PPA and install the package using the PPA.

Comment: Also, running `dpkg -i` directly can be dangerous, since `dpkg` does not take care of install dependencies.