# Syspeek for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ppa, system-monitor

I've used syspeek since 12.04. It's a nice little tool that monitors system stats, like memory usage and processing usage, very neatly.

My version of syspeek broke when I updated to 13.10 and I was hoping there would be a way to still use it.
How can I install a version that works with Ubuntu 13.10?

There is a repository mentioned in the answers for this question, however it is, when I checked, still for 13.04:
[How can I install Syspeek in Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290662/how-can-i-install-syspeek-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to get syspeek working again. (tested on 14.04) :

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-syspeek-0-3-on-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-13-10-ubuntu-12-10-and-ubuntu-12-04/

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install syspeek
```

Enjoy!